# How to loop on an Array of Objects on ionic 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I have an array of objects on my application TS file I'm populating my array with an object that I'm getting from the storage.

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen } from 'ionic-native';
import { Dbservice } from '../providers/dbservice';

import { Home } from '../pages/page1/page1';
 import { Setup } from '../pages/frameSetup/setup';

export class Home {
    deviceObj = [];
     constructor(){
         this.deviceObj.push(otherObject);
     }
}
```

on my html file I want to look on the array and display the data, but when I do this I get an error message

Here is the code on my html file.

```
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col width-10 *ngFor="let x of deviceObj">
      <button ion-button outline icon-only small>
        <ion-icon name="ios-add"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col width-10>
      <button ion-button outline icon-only small [navPush]="setupPage">
        <ion-icon name="ios-add"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

I get an error saying that :

> polyfills.js:3 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse
>   errors: Can't bind to 'ngforOf' since it isn't a known property of
>   'ion-col'.
>   1. If 'ion-col' is an Angular component and it has 'ngforOf' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'ion-col' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Comment: ngFor. I'm trying to covert an angular1 to 2. What I'm missing on the syntax? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `BrowserModule` to `imports: [...]` of `AppModule` if this is where your code is, or alternatively add `CommonModule` to `imports: [...]` if your code is in another module.

The error message means that the `NgFor` directive is not known in the module. Importing `CommonModule` or `BrowserModule` (`AppModule` only) makes it available.

Comment: Thanka for the info, I added the imports I have, guess I'm missing some.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you just can't use *ngFor in  tag. Try using it inside  tag and the error will disappear.